# Swift URL appendingPathComponent converts `?` to `%3F`

Tags: ios, swift, url, swift4

```
let url = URL(string: "https://example.com")
let path = "/somePath?"
let urlWithPath = url?.appendingPathComponent(path)
```

After appending, the path `/somePath?` becomes `somePath%3F`.

The `?` becomes a `%3F`. Question Mark is replaced with the percent-encoded escape characters.

The URL does output correctly if I use:

```
let urlFormString = URL(string:"https://example.com/somePath?")
```

Why does `appendingPathComponent` convert `?` to `%3F`?

How can I use `appendingPathComponent` if the path component contains a question mark?

Comment: When you call `appendingPathComponent`, you shouldn’t include either the leading `/` nor the trailing `?`. If you want to add query to URL, you should consider using `URLComponents`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The generic format of URL is the following:

```
scheme:[//[userinfo@]host[:port]]path[?query][#fragment]
```

The thing you have to realize is that the `?` is not part of the `path`. It is a separator between `path` and `query`.

If you try to add `?` to path, it must be URL-encoded because `?` is not a valid character for a path component.

The best solution would be to drop `?` from `path`. It has no meaning there. However, if you have a partial URL which you want to append to a base URL, then you should join them as strings:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://example.com")
let path = "/somePath?"
let urlWithPath = url.flatMap { URL(string: $0.absoluteString + path) }
```

In short, `appendingPathComponent` is not a function that should be used to append URL query.

Answer (score 9):

You should use `removingPercentEncoding` on URL's `absoluteString`,

```
let url = URL(string: "https://example.com")
let path = "/somePath?"
let urlWithPath = url?.appendingPathComponent(path).absoluteString.removingPercentEncoding
print(urlWithPath!)
```

Comment: Unless `URL` contains other characters that should be URL encoded, because then this "solution" would break.

Comment: I was looking for this!
You saved my day :D

Answer (score 0):

`%3F` stands for `?`, according to URL Encoding. So if you create an URL - it has to be that way. If, for some reason, you need your `?`, create a string, not URL.

Check `urlWithPath.lastPathComponent` to see that everything is all right (prints: "somePath?")

Answer (score 0):

When you convert the string to URL, It'll be doing PercentEncoding in URL. So that your `?` has been encoded into `%3F`.

If you want the url as string with `?`, you can remove the PercentEncoding as like below code.

`let urlString = urlWithPath?.absoluteString.removingPercentEncoding`

`Output: https://example.com/somePath?`

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is not a problem. this is a mechanism called URL encoding, for translating unprintable or special characters to a universally accepted format by web servers and browsers.

For more information you can go to https://www.techopedia.com/definition/10346/url-encoding

URL encoded chars, https://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php

Answer (score 0):

Instead of URL can use URLComponents:

```
var url = URLComponents()
```

Set the scheme, host and path:

```
url.scheme = "https"
url.host = "example.com"
url.path = "/somePath"
```

Set the query as empty string and ? is added since it is a separator between path and query:

```
url.query = ""
// url.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "nameN", value: "valueX")]
```

Prints: `https://example.com/somePath?`

```
print(url)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can build your url using `NSString` class:

```
let urlStr = "https://example.com" as NSString
let path = "/somePath?"
let urlStrWithPath = urlStr.appendingPathComponent(path)
let url = URL(string: urlStrWithPath)
```

This way, special characters are not url-encoded in the final url.